# procfile no changing from web to worker

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I'm trying to Host my bot "chompbot" in Heroku.
But when i change Procfile from web to worker, does not change anything.

I've tried

Here is my package.json

```
  "name": "chompbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1"
  }
}
```

And here is my Procfile

`worker: index.js`

When i commit and push, anything happens on "Web", and do not appears "Worker" option
( Ps.: The MySql database is fully working on cloud, so, can't be the dependencies )

Can someone help me to change from Web to Worker?
http://prntscr.com/pb21qs

Answer (score 0):

Your worker should be the script that starts you server, index.js is only the file name. What you want to do is to use your `npm start` script instead of `index.js`

Comment: But in ```package.json``` i set ```scripts: {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }```, npm start are the same in comparison with ```"node index.js"```

Comment: It has to be a script.